# MFMailComposeViewController IOS

Tags: ios, xcode

At the moment I have a NSArray of emails, and I open a view to end an email to all of these emails:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[mailer setSubject:@"App Support"];

NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithArray:emails];
[mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];

NSString *emailBody = @"";
[mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

// only for iPad
mailer.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;

[self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];
```

Is there a way to send an email to this list without opening actually opening the controller (the user won't need to press on the send button and can't change the message)??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to send the message using the `MFMailComposeViewController`.

If you want to send an email "silently", I have previously used [SKPSMTPMessage](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/) - an SMTP client that can  be used on iOS to send emails without any UI.

You can set up a Gmail account specifically for the purpose of sending the messages if required.

I've created a simple demo for you. [Download it here](https://www.yousendit.com/download/WUJiTGs1Qk44aVBxYk1UQw). Note that, along with the files in the SMTP folder, you will need to link to the `CFNetwork.framework` in your project.

Comment: I think its a great alternative, but where can I actually find the xcode sample project?

Comment: but the point is that when the user uses the app, they are going to send those emails, not me, and the process requires their password, which I don't know, and their host

Comment: As my answer mentions, you can set up an email address (or use an existing one) to send the emails. You won't be able to use the user's own email account to send with this method.

Comment: Added link to demo for you.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the great job, i'll have a look at it tomorrow since now it's time to sleep! (I am in Italy)

Comment: Another question I have: if the user sends the emails to may by 20 emails, and in the middle of the process we closes the app, will the emails still be sent?

Comment: But I have a linker problem: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530736/skpsmtpmessage-liker-error

Comment: I suggest you run some tests to check what happens when the app is closed. If the message has been created and sent to the SMTP server (gmail), then the emails should be sent.